# Remove bulk user access SQL Server from many servers using Power Shell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a script to remove a user from SQL Server using a PowerShell command, but this script can only remove from 1 server only per execute, and the userlist are in the execute script

This is the script

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
$Error.Clear()
cls
 
$servers = Get-Content c:\Test\Servers.txt
$logins =  @("DOMAIN\ALEX","DOMAIN\BERY")
 
foreach($server in $servers)
{
    $srv = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $server
     
    #drop database users
    foreach($database in $srv.Databases)
    {
        foreach($login in $logins)
        {
            if($database.Users.Contains($login))
            {
                $database.Users[$login].Drop();
            }
        }
    }
     
    #drop server logins
    foreach($login in $logins)
    {
        if ($srv.Logins.Contains($login)) 
        { 
            $srv.Logins[$login].Drop(); 
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the script the server list are using the c:\Test\Servers.txt. I tried to create many servers in the servers.txt but it always error.

This is the list in servers.txt

```
10.20.121.100
```

I was wondering how to remove many users from many servers per execute and the list of the userlogin also in the txt file not in the execute script.

Comment: and this is why we use roles (and groups), to assign perms, and not users!

Comment: Use a similar approach to read the logins using Get-Content instead of hardcoding the names in the script.

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and check log files in the explorer under Management.